# Best ORM, Simple data Structures, Strong Query analysis

Tags: database, orm

What is the best ORM db combination for simple data structures. That is data that contains names as identifiers and locations, but whose main interaction will be numerical data for times(sports durations), and currency related data.

I initially want to create a sports data base that will take names and statistics. Secondarily I plan to start into an investment and stock analysis db.

Which ORM suits storing many numerical types and have strong query functions?

I really am not biased to db engine (most likely use sqlite or mongo) so any suggestions to best network less db server to suit said ORM appreciated.

I had reviewed several options but I don't want to influence any suggestion or opinion. But for reference.

Genstone/Glass - Smalltalk/Pharo/Squeak 
Magma - Pharo/Squeak 
SQLalchemy - Python 
Sequel - Ruby 
Access/Excel - Micorosoft
I am learning scheme but haven't seen an ORM on offer via Racket or Chicken at the moment.
Dabo - python

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on platform/language?  It seems that's how most people approach determining which ORM library to use.

Comment: No real restriction, I have a windows Xp, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.10 to work from.

Comment: Edit: I realised thats not what you meant after I walked away. I am not tied to a platform, no boss to please,have no concerns about employment or fashion I just want to get some opinon as to the best tools for for above stated situation. Only restriction cannot afford commercial packages.

Comment: Before picking an ORM, you should pick a programming language and one or more database vendors.  Also, Mongo is not a relational database, so there is no need for an ORM in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that there is no need for an ORM with NoSQL, e.g., mongodb.  If there is any difference in the data store from the way objects are created, modified, inter-related, found and deleted in the programming environment then that different needs to be made as small and non-obtrusive as possible.  This it the job of an ORM when working with a RDBMS.  But in principle the problem of mapping objects in one or more languages to a persistent store is much broader than just the subset when the persistent store is a relational database.

Today with multiple levels of distributed and local store the problem is larger, not smaller. Data can be spread from process memory to local shared memory to local disk stores which may be an arbitrary mix of SSD and HD and from there to distributed memory (e.g., memcache) and remote possibly replicated stores.  Not to mention mobile, local, cloud.

THe problem that ORM is made to solve is deeper and wider today.

I wrote my first ORM in 1987 from Objective C to a relational database core (file level).  I then worked for an object database company a few years interfacing languages to their ODBMS. Even with an object database there was some mismatch and need for language specific powerful but transparent interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to say that the best ORM I have used is [The Sharp Factory](https://www.thesharpfactory.com/)

It can handle thousands of tables and creates a repository, interfaces, entities and all of the code needed to interact with the databse.

The downside is that it only supports C#.